# Why doesn't my .pushViewController work from didSelectItemAt in swift

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I am trying to push a viewController when i user selects a item from a list through the didSelectItemAt function but when ever a user selects the item nothing happens.

This is how my didSelectItemAt function looks so far:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print(stores[indexPath.row].storeName)
    let myStore = UserStoreVC(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
    myStore.store = stores[indexPath.row]
    navigationController?.pushViewController(myStore, animated: true)
}
```

This is how i have set up my UserStoreVC class:

```
class UserStoreVC: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {}
```

When a user selects the item the function does get called as the store name is printed correctly through the print function but nothing is being presented and i am not sure why not.

Have i done something wrong as this is how i have pushed other viewControllers in the same app and it works correctly

how do i make it work?

when i add a breakpoint to this line i get this:

[image]

DiscoverCollection Collection View:

```
let collectionView: DiscoverCollection = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    let view = DiscoverCollection(collectionViewLayout: layout)
    return view
}()
```

Comment: Make a breakePoint at navigationController?.pushViewController(myStore, animated: true)
} and check navigationcontroller is nil or not.

Comment: i added a picture of the breakpoint result i don't see navigationController

Comment: navigationController is nil because when i add an if statement to check if its nil it comes back true

Comment: So this is your issue. You need to make a navigation controller  for your VC in Storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Look here step by step for adding NavigationController for your ViewController :
[image]

Step 2: Click to add NavigationController for your VC.
[image]

Step 3: Finally you have navigationController.
[image]

Comment: I'm doing everything programmatically. And it is already a navicationController

Comment: So did you got solution or need any help?

Comment: no it is still not working and would appreciate your help

Comment: This collections view is placed inside of a header of another collectionView. Would this be why its not working?

Comment: Nope. First fix navigationController issue. This is only issue. Try to pass navigationController object from VC to this CollectionView class and then try to navigate.

Comment: How would i do that because inside of the header i have registered an cell and inside of the cell i created a collectionView called DiscoverCollection i've added the code above.